# WHat exactly mule 'clean redeployment' mean?

Tags: mule

I want to redeploy an app on mule standalone (hot deployment). 
I need to be sure that if some flows are processing data, when I start the deployment of the new version of the app, it waits for all old messages are processed before deploying it.

Moreover, the app includes jmsQ (publisher/subscribers pattern), if there still are messages on jmsQ, will there process with new version of the app or the old version of the app.
I was unable to find response for this purpose, if one of you have better documentation or a part of the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience, if you are going to redeploy an app, the mule app is stopped first, the message on the "flow" that it is currently processing will be "lost". When the "new" flow will then connect to ActiveMQ and process the remaining message from  queue. Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Sadly yes, i was afraid of that.
I can't lose the message, and need to wait for the end of the flow before redeploy.
I know how to stop a flow, but dont find out how i can know when the message is processed (from a other flow which will stop the first one).